# Javascript confirm actions

Tags: javascript

I have a page with one continue button. If I click on continue then 
all the above 3 popups come on after the other if I click OK for the popups, but if I click Cancel on a popup then the page should get closed, which is done by my `closeAction();` method.

If I click cancel for the 1st or 2nd popups the page is not being closed, but the 3rd works.

```
if(document.getElementById(id1).value){
    if(!confirm("click Cancel to Close page and ok to go to next popup")){
         closeAction();
    }
       }

if(document.getElementById(id2).value){        
       if(!confirm("click Cancel to Close page and ok to go to next popup")){
        closeAction();
    }
       }
if(!confirm(" to be made click 'Cancel'")){
        closeAction();
         }
```

Comment: What does closeAction() look like?

Comment: function closeAction(){
  parent.close();
  var anyNew = 'false';
     if(parent.frames['files']!=null){
       anyNew = parent.frames['files'].document.getElementById("docForm:anyNewDocument").value;
     }
  if(anyNew == "true") {   //New Doc available Dont make server call  
    return false;
     }
     return true;
 }

Answer (score 1):

Use else, so that you skip the rest of the checks once you called the closeAction method:

```
if (document.getElementById(id1).value && !confirm("click Cancel to Close page and ok to go to next popup")) {
   closeAction();
} else if (document.getElementById(id2).value && !confirm("click Cancel to Close page and ok to go to next popup")) {
   closeAction();
} else if (!confirm(" to be made click 'Cancel'")) {
   closeAction();
}
```

Comment: but all the popus should come

Comment: @suresh: Even if you click cancel on the first?

Answer (score 0):

Remember, `&&` is short-circuiting:

```
if (document.getElementById(id1).value &&
    !confirm("click Cancel to Close page and ok to go to next popup") &&
    document.getElementById(id2).value &&
    !confirm("click Cancel to Close page and ok to go to next popup") &&
    !confirm(" to be made click 'Cancel'"))
{
    closeAction();
}
```